# Как изменить пропускную способность логического порта?

Tags: сеть, порт

Здравствуйте! А можно ли как-то изменить пропускную способность логического порта? Например порта 80-го?

Comment: Использовать более серьёзную аппаратуру. Или Вы имели в виду какую-то специфическую проблему?

Comment: какая OS ? в линуксе tc.

Comment: Например в Windows хочу чтобы порт 1000 не пропускал более 5 кб/с. Ну к примеру в программе-торренте как-то ограничивают скорость загрузки... И как они это делают?